# PHP precedence operator A? 'True': 'False'

Tags: php

I facing a problem where i put more condition into this statement `A? 'True': 'False'`

As what i know the Associativity of ?: is from the left

This is the example

`(1 == 2)?'a':(2==3)?'b':'c'`  =   answer 'c'
`(1 == 2)?'a':(2==2)?'b':'c'`    =   answer 'b'

As what i know `(1 == 2)==false` , then it went to false condition `(2==3)` and false return so the answer is c (might be wrong, please correct me)

Above example work fine, but it start to went wrong when

`(1 == 1)?'a':(2==3)?'b':'c'`  =   answer 'b'
`(1 == 1)?'a':(2==2)?'b':'c'`    =   answer 'b'

As what i know
`(1 == 1) == true`, so it should pick the 'a' and ignore the rest.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Sidenote: I advise you either use brackets to clarify your logic or better stop using such constructions. Other programmers will hardly like them.

Comment: As for your question - all your conditions are executed like `((1 == 2)?'a':(2==3))?'b':'c'`

Comment: I'm not sure, but i might single line if statement (ternary logic) doesn't allow you to have multiple conditions....

Comment: It is OK to have multiple conditions @GuilhermeLopes

Comment: It's executed like @u_mulder already said.. you must use brackets to group the expressions: `1 == 1 ? 'a ' : (2==3 ? 'b' : 'c')`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hmmm... I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: But after i group it `((1 == 1)?'a':(2==3))?'b':'c'` it still return 'b'

Comment: Because that grouping is not correct, you're putting the evaluations together improperly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement `(1 == 1) ? 'a' : (2 == 3) ? 'b' : 'c'`, the first condition statement does return `'a'`, but since there's another condition statement right after your first, it wants to compare `'a'` for `true` or `false`. Since a `string` in a condition statement will always return `true`, the second condition statement returns `'b'`.

You're going to want to use your statement as follows:

```
(1 == 1) ? 'a' : ((2 == 3) ? 'b' : 'c')
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, it enhance my understanding.

Answer (score 6):

Nested ternaries can be problematic in as much as it is hard to *read* what is going on. Bracketing properly cures the issue:

```
(1 === 1) ? 'a' : ((2==3) ? 'b' : 'c')
```

This reads like this: if 1 equals 1 then a, else perform if 2 equals 3.

Comment: the brackets from the evaluated expressions are not mandatory, unless multiple expressions are trying to be evaluated in the same statement.. I don't use them for readability: `1 === 1 ? 'a' : (2 === 3 ? 'b' : 'c')`

Comment: Everyone's mileage varies on this @MateiMihai, but I do agree with you and I personally do not use brackets on the evaluations.. I wanted to show the OP in *their* context what the test would look like.

Comment: Thank for your answer, it enhance my understanding.